# The root of OS special Linux and Unix and so on

Tags: filesystem, syslinux, minix

what is really Debian and how does it work and why in every Linux and Unix its written then it based in debian and so on and loooooppp

Comment: Ask this kind of question in chat or restate your question. We can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: Debian isn't the root of all Linux Distributions. It is one of the main ones. Your question is too broad because it opens the doors to a whole book of decades in history...IMO.

Comment: First of all, your question is off-topic and poorly formated. Second, not all Linux distributions are based on Debian- Arch is one example. Debian is relatively hardware-independent and has an easy-to-use package manager.

Answer (score 2):

In very simple terms, each version of linux has the same core functions but a slightly different file structure and some different apps. Think of it this way, if you were planting a garden, you might put your radishes close to the gate because you like radishes, or you may put them far from the gate because you only eat them occasionally. The radishes are there in both gardens, just in different places.

There is a very interesting "family tree" that shows the many linux types that have been derived from Debian at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions. Unlike Windows or MAC OS/X, because linux is open source, many people have played with it and produced useful variations.

Comment: Interesting analogy... haven't heard that one before :p

Comment: I like this analogy too!